# How do you get Firebase collection items along with their keys

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

My function returns items that do not have keys.

```
getByYear(yr) {
    return this.db
      .collection('contracts', ref => ref.orderBy('amount', 'desc').where('financialYear', '==', yr))
      .valueChanges();
  }
```

How do i include item keys in the returned set when using collections with angularfire2. All solutions i have seen seem to work with lists and not collections.

Comment: If your preferred method of getting document data from Firestore involves eliminating the document IDs from the query results, you'll need to put the id of the document into the document itself as a new field.  Or, you'll have to query in such a way that you get an entire DocumentSnapshot object to deal with (which has an `id` property).

Answer (score 1):

From the [AngularFire documentation for `valueChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#valuechanges):

> **When would you not use it?**
>
> When you need a more complex data structure than an array or **you need the id of each document** to use data manipulation methods. This method assumes you either are saving the id to the document data or using a "readonly" approach.

Since you need the ID of the documents, either use [`documentChanges](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges) or [persist the ID into the document too](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#example-of-persisting-a-document-id).